# How to pass in DayTemplateContext TemplateRef of NgBootstrap DatePicker

Tags: angular, angular5, ng-bootstrap

I want to use the NgBootstrap TimeRange Picker (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples)

The only thing not working yet is the display of the range for which I have to hand in the DayTemplateContext TemplateRef. Something like this:

```
constructor(config: NgbDatepickerConfig) {
    config.displayMonths = 3;
    config.dayTemplate = this.thisIsTheVariableINeed; <--------

    const todayNGB = calendar.getToday();
    const today = new Date(todayNGB.year, todayNGB.month, todayNGB.day);
    config.markDisabled = (date: NgbDateStruct) => {
      const d = new Date(date.year, date.month - 1, date.day);
      return d > today;
    };
}
```

How do I get that TemplateRef I have defined it in the html of the same component:

```
<ng-template #asdasd let-date="date" let-focused="focused">
  <span class="custom-day"
        [class.focused]="focused"
        [class.range]="isFrom(date) || isTo(date) || isInside(date) || isHovered(date)"
        [class.faded]="isHovered(date) || isInside(date)"
        (mouseenter)="hoveredDate = date"
        (mouseleave)="hoveredDate = null">
    {{ date.day }}
  </span>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I wanted to do this is because I didn't realise that you can pass in the [startDate] in the html instead of the controller.